# TS2532 - Object is possibly undefined - useRef and react-three-fiber

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tslint, react-three-fiber

I'm implementing a component with react-three-fiber that looks like this:

```
const Controls = (props: any) => {
        const controlsRef = useRef();
        const { camera, gl } = useThree();

        useFrame(() => controlsRef.current && controlsRef!.current!.update());
        // ^ Errors with Object is possibly 'undefined'

        useFrame(() => {
            if (controlsRef !== undefined && controlsRef.current !== undefined) {
                controlsRef.current.target = new THREE.Vector3(worldMap.length / 2 * CELL_WIDTH, 0, worldMap.length / 2 * CELL_WIDTH)
                // ^ ALSO errors with Object is possibly undefined
            }
        })

        return (
            <orbitControls
                {...props}
                ref={controlsRef}
                args={[camera, gl.domElement]}
                enableRotate
                enablePan={false}
                maxDistance={100}
                minDistance={5}
                maxPolarAngle={Math.PI / 3}
            />
        );
    };
```

I've tried adding:

```
if (controlsRef !== undefined && controlsRef.current !== undefined) {
    controlsRef!.current!.target = ...
    // Errors with target does not exist on type 'never'
}
```

As well as:

```
useFrame(() => controlsRef.current && controlsRef?.current?.update());
// Errors with update does not exist on type 'never'
```

Alas to no avail. I feel like I'm bashing my head against an immovable Typescript wall!

What am I doing wrong?

(Can create a code sandbox if needed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to provide the types for `useRef`'s genetic type parameter, and initialise it as null.

```
const controlsRef = useRef<OrbitControls>(null);
```

I am not sure the exact interface/typing to use as I am unfamiliar with the library you are working with, but this is the general idea.

In addition, in your useEffect hook, it will be sufficient to use optional chaining (provided if you are working with TypeScript 3.7.5 and above)

```
useFrame(() => controlsRef?.current?.update());
```

Comment: Derp. I had to add my own types for the Library, and I totally missed this. I added the type to useRef and it works! But when I add null as the default, I get an error on `controlsRef.current.target =`... I'm confused again... Surely if I don't put null it would default to null/undefined?

Comment: Hmm.. Yes, if you don't put null, it will be `undefined`. What is the error you are facing now?

Comment: So if I add null as the default, I get the line `controlsRef.current.target = ...` with an error of "Object is possibly 'null'". It works completely fine if I leave the default as undefined though..

Comment: Hmm.. If we leave it as undefined, are there no other issues? In that case, let's leave it as `undefined` :) At the end of the day, it shouldn't matter anyways because `controlsRef` will definitely be assigned with the ref from `OrbitControls`

Comment: Yup. Pretty much my thoughts. Because it's a useRef I don't _think_ it should cause any issues. Thanks!